# Tensorflow ReLU normalizes strangely

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

in my opinion the rectified linear unit is supposed to execute the following function:

```
relu(x) = max(x, 0)
```

However, this seems not to be the case with `tf.nn.relu`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
rand_large = np.random.randn(10, 3)*100
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 3])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.nn.relu(X), feed_dict={X:rand_large})
```

The random matrix looks like this:

```
>>> rand_large
array([[  21.94064161,  -82.16632876,   16.25152777],
   [  55.54897693,  -93.15235155,  118.99166126],
   [ -13.36452239,   39.36508285,   65.42844521],
   [-193.34041145,  -97.08632376,   99.22162259],
   [  87.02924619,    2.04134891,  -27.29975745],
   [-181.11406687,   43.55952393,   42.29312993],
   [ -29.81242188,   93.5764354 , -165.62711447],
   [  17.78380711, -171.30536766, -197.20709038],
   [ 105.94903623,   34.07995616,   -7.27568839],
   [-100.59533697, -189.88957685,   -7.52421816]])
```

And the output from the relu function like this:

```
>>> sess.run(tf.nn.relu(X), feed_dict={X:rand_large})array([[ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
   [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5]], dtype=float32)
```

**So, if I see it correctly, `tf.nn.relu` does some sort of normalization, right? If yes, why isn't it mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu)?**

Okay, I found out that the whole issue was related to my tensorflow installtion which seemed to be corrupt. On another machine, I did get the expected results.
Thank you for the help and helpful comments.

Comment: The output you have mentioned is wrong, you should get negative values as zero and positive values retained.

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get the output that you mentioned.

Comment: Really strange... Maybe this is my installation of TF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.nn.relu` does not normalize the data. For example, if I run

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 3])
relu_X=tf.nn.relu(X)

sess = tf.Session()
mat = np.array([[-1,2,3],[2,-5,1]])
sess.run(relu_X, feed_dict={X:mat})
```

the result is

```
array([[ 0.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=float32)
```